# связка Node.js + MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Бот отказывается считывать/изменять данные в MongoDB, хотя новые документы без проблем создает.
https://gist.github.com/Kittyasd/b6a828ad1915ac82c494f37457567bf4 - в результате вызова `${prefix}givebounty` - ничего не происходит
https://gist.github.com/Kittyasd/3bb6d625906b053388f50eff4f3dace9 - в результате вызова `${prefix}givebounty` - бот каждый раз создает новый документ в MongoDB, хотя должен редактировать старый.
P.s. пишу бота для Discord с помощью Discord.js(но это не суть важно).
Подскажите все ли в порядке с синтаксисом моего кода, или возможно есть другие причины неработоспособности считывания данных из MongoDB.

Comment: прикладывайте, пожалуйста, код непосредственно в тело вопроса. Большинство участников не будет вчитываться и переходить по сторонним ссылкам и просто будет игнорировать данный вопрос.

Comment: @МихаилРебров, (gist.github) в данном случае я с вами не согласен

Comment: @Kitty1234, по первой ссылке, в gist.github, не указано расширение файла (`js`) поэтому отсутствует подсветка синтаксиса - исправьте, а так же приведите скобки в порядок

Comment: @qwabra, я не пытаюсь сказать,  что ссылка github не вызывает доверия (хотя с другими проектами и ссылками это тоже является проблемой). Я просто говорю, что правильно и хорошо оформленный вопрос привлекает больше внимания и увеличивает вероятность быстрого и хорошего ответа. Как таковая ссылка на гитхаб имеет место быть и часто может быть полезной при решении вопроса, но для того чтобы дойти до того, чтобы лезть к человеку в репозиторий и разбираться было бы для начала неплохо хотя бы в первом приближении понять, а в чем собственно проблема.